# TFVC doesn't detect removed files while merging

Tags: tfs, version-control, tfvc

We have a project where we mostly use two branches: one for development, let's call it "Main" and one where we merge code to be released, let's call it "Release". Release branch was created from Main branch using Visual Studio (right click on Main branch => Branch - that's how we created Release branch). In Main branch we have two files, after we merged everything to the Release branch it also contains those two files. Later, if we delete one of the files in Main branch and then try to merge changes to Release branch it doesn't detect that difference. We expect that merging tool should detect that one file has to be deleted.

How then we ensure that later when we have more than two files we can trust tfs that it will detect deletion and will properly merge changes? 
Is there any setup to be done to make it possible?

Example:

In branch M we have two folders: SolutionA and SolutionB. SolutionA is our package where we check-in modifications. SolutionB is a solution provided by an independent software vendor(ISV), from time to time that ISV sends us a new version of their solution which we have to check-in into corresponding folder. The thing is that it often happens that they delete some objects in their package and create new one. With new objects everything works fine, but with those which they've deleted - doesn't.

How do we deploy new version? - Take a development environment and remove SolutionB folder from the locally mapped directory, deploy a new version of SolutionB on that environment and then check-in. As a result only new items get to the source control, those items which were deleted by ISV remain in repository. Therefore any developer who gets latest version on his devbox is getting only new files which is clear as no delete action was checked-in for them. And second point - when we want to merge new version of SolutionB to Release branch we only add new items there.

To track manually which files were deleted is not an option as SolutionB has thousands of items inside. Therefore i'm wondering what is wrong with my setup that in the moment when i'm checking-in new version of SolutionB from a devbox VCS cannot detect that old items are deleted (as they're not present in local mapped folder).

For a better understanding take a look at image:

[image]

Let's say that version 1 of SolutionB contains FileFour and FileThree. Version 2 contains FileThree and FileFive. This would mean that after i check-in version 2 to VCS it will only add FileFive to the SolutionB folder and won't remove FileFour. As a result while merging from branch M to branch R i will get all 3 files in R branch in SolutionB folder.

We're using Vistual Studio 2015 and Azure DevOps Services

Comment: Which versions of TFS and VS do you use? Do you check in the changes after you delete the file? I'm not able to reproduce your issue, the `delete` pending change merges successfully. You may provide detailed steps how to reproduce your issue, screenshots would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using VS 2015, you can install [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power), and then right click V2 of SolutionB, select **Team Foundation Server -- Detected Change**, to promote pending changes, you'll see the deleted files.

[image]

Or you need to delete SolutionB from Source Control Explorer and check in the changes, then add new version of SolutionB in your workspace, to check in new version.

By the way, you may invite your vendor to your DevOps and use the same repo to work together.

Comment: Ended up with a workaround to delete solution from source control and then check-in new version as no other alternatives were found